# How to get payload of each and every notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent

I'm using different msg id to show notification in my app, when i click notificaion how could i get the payload or msg of each notificaion to show relevant info to the user.

[multiple notificaion http://trip38.com/images/noti.png](http://trip38.com/images/noti.png)

A good reference or workaround would be more helpful :)

Code i had written is

```
NotificationManager notifier = (NotificationManager) GCMIntentService.this.
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(drawable, msg_alert, System.currentTimeMillis());

    //Setup the Intent to open this Activity when clicked
    Intent toLaunch = new Intent(GCMIntentService.this, MainActivity.class);
    toLaunch.putExtra("msg", msg);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(GCMIntentService.this, 0, toLaunch, 0);

    //Set the Notification Info
    notification.tickerText = ticker_msg;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(GCMIntentService.this, noti_title, noti_msg, contentIntent);

    //Setting Notification Flags
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

    notifier.notify(msg_id, notification);
```

**EDIT Code**

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;

public GCMIntentService() {
    super(AppConstants.SENDER_ID);
}


@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
    mPreferences = context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.PREFS_FILE_NAME, 0);

    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPreferences.edit();
    mEditor.putString(AppConstants.REGISTRATION_KEY_STR, registrationId);
    mEditor.apply();

    //saved reg id in server
}

@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    Logger.d(TAG, "unregistered = " + arg1);
}

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    Logger.d(TAG, "new message received: " + arg1.getStringExtra("message"));
    showNotification(arg1.getStringExtra("message"));
}

@Override
protected void onError(Context arg0, String errorId) {
    Logger.d(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}

private void showNotification(String msg) {
    String msg_alert = getResources().getString(R.string.app_name); //alert notification title
    String noti_title = ""; //noti_title from msg
    String noti_msg = ""; //noti_msg from msg
    String ticker_msg = ""; //ticker_msg from msg
    String msg_icon = ""; //msg_icon from msg
    int msg_id; //msg_id from msg

    //Get the icon for the notification
    int drawable = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    if (!msg_icon.equals(""))
        drawable = getResources().getIdentifier(msg_icon, "drawable", getPackageName());
    if (drawable == 0) {
        drawable = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    }
    NotificationManager notifier = (NotificationManager) GCMIntentService.this.
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(drawable, msg_alert, System.currentTimeMillis());

    //Setup the Intent to open this Activity when clicked
    Intent toLaunch = new Intent(GCMIntentService.this, MainActivity.class);
    toLaunch.putExtra("msg_type", msg_type);
    toLaunch.putExtra("trip_id", trip_id);
    toLaunch.putExtra("booking_id", booking_id);
    toLaunch.putExtra("noty_ticket_id", ticketId);
    toLaunch.putExtra("msg", msg);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(GCMIntentService.this, 0, toLaunch, 0);

    //Set the Notification Info
    notification.tickerText = ticker_msg;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(GCMIntentService.this, noti_title, noti_msg, contentIntent);

    //Setting Notification Flags
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    notifier.notify(msg_id, notification);
}
```

}

Comment: Are you adding pending intent to your notification builder? Please put some code.

Comment: It's not recommended by Google to display notifications like that: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html

Comment: @Rohit5k2 added code for reference.

Comment: @Groco yes i read that article, but even tough i implemented it because each notification might have different event. For example in Google now app there are different events like flight delay, sports result, stock updates, etc...

Comment: Its not helpful to down vote a question without _mentioning the reason_ :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(GCMIntentService.this, 0,
                                         toLaunch, 0);
```

If you are creating several `PendingIntent`s that need to be active simultaneously, you need to ensure that they are "unique". The easiest way to do that is to use a different (unique) `requestCode` parameter when calling `PendingIntent.getActivity()`. Like this:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(GCMIntentService.this, msg_id,
                                         toLaunch, 0);
```

(This assumes that `msg_id` is unique for each message. If it isn't, you can use some other unique number.

Comment: Is there any way to get the payload from pending intent if the app is already opened when the notification is clicked?

Comment: Yes. Add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` to the `Intent` that you put in the `Notification` (`toLaunch`). The method `onNewIntent()` will be called in `MainActivity` and this `Intent` should have your payload (extras) in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you will receive data in activity `MainActivity`. You will get the payload passed from notification to intent.

```
String msgFromNotification =  getIntent().getStringExtra("msg")
```

**EDIT**

Probably value of `msg` is static. See you code. If you want to receive the message displayed on the notification

Change

```
toLaunch.putExtra("msg", msg);
```

to

```
toLaunch.putExtra("msg", noti_msg);
```

Comment: Exactly the same, but in `msgFromNotification` i'm only getting the payload of Title6 even i clicked the Title1.

Comment: `String msg = arg1.getStringExtra("message")`
this is how i'm getting msg from `onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1)`

Comment: Did you try my code? Also please add complete class code. There is something wrong in other part.

Comment: if `noti_title` and `noti_msg` is blank how is it being displayed on the notification? Also you have a log in `onMessage` method. Does it display right value?